# Advice on window flashing

Tags: flashing

Renovating our 1950’s garage and updating windows. Contractor inset the windows to match the house and placed flashing over the windows and nothing under the window casing, which is in direct contact with the wood. Is this right or do I need them to fix it? I live in California with no snow if that matters

Comment: Please [edit] this to add a picture or two.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Hard to tell from your description alone, but if you're saying there's no [pan flashing](https://buildingscience.com/documents/information-sheets/pan-flashing-for-exterior-wall-openings), (between the bottom of the framed opening and the window) yeah, that's generally required by code. And common sense.

On the other hand, there should NOT be flashing tape on the *outside* of the window at the bottom. *That* needs to be open so the pan flashing can drain properly.

[One code reference](https://codes.iccsafe.org/content/IRC2018P7/chapter-7-wall-covering#IRC2018P7_Pt03_Ch07_SecR703.4) see 703.4.1.1